# is it possible to get another view's width in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make this design , can we get another widget's width ?

[As per shown in image I want to make underline below the Text widget and width of Text is wrap so underline width is also change according to Text name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZH6N.png)

Comment: You can try using Layout builder which can help you find parent widget's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this approach?

```
 Text(
      "Some Text With Underline",
      softWrap: true,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        decoration: textdecoration,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contribution guys, as I am beginner in flutter UI design.And have find the easiest solution for the above question.yes its looks so easy when I have found solutions.
Thanks

the solutions is :

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: BorderDirectional(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 2,
                style: BorderStyle.solid
              )
            )
          ),
          child: Text('Any text',
              softWrap: true,
              style: YourClassName.of(context)
                  .commonTextStyle(FontWeight.w600, 0xffffffff, 0.4, 16)),
        )
```